# PHP parse street address with abbreviations from text input for search

Tags: php, arrays, regex, parsing, search

I need to parse a street address in PHP a string that might have abbreviations. 
This string comes from a text input. 
The fields I need to search are:

- street (alphanumeric - might have
- building (alphanumeric - might have
- number (alphanumeric - might have
- area (numeric from 1 to 5)
- other (unknown field & used to search in all the above fields in the database)

For example users submits one of this text text:

1. street Main Road Bulding H7 Number 5 Area 1
2. st Main Road bldg H7 Nr 5 Ar 5
3. stMain bldgh7
4. ar5 unknown other search parameter
5. street Main Road h7 2b
6. street main street str main road

The outcome I would like to see as a array:

1. [street]=>Main Road [building]=>h7 [number]=>5 [area]=>1
2. [street]=>Main Road [building]=>h7 [number]=>5 [area]=>5
3. [street]=>Main [building]=>h7
4. [area]=>5 [other]=>unknown other search parameter
5. [street]=>Main Road [other]=>h7 2b
6. [street]=>Main Street&&Main Road

My code so far...but dosen't work with examples 3.,4.,5.,6.:

```
<?php
//posted address
$address = "str main one bldg 5b other param area 1";
//to replace
$replace = ['street'=>['st','str'],
            'building'=>['bldg','bld'],
            'number'=>['nr','numb','nmbr']];
//replace
foreach($replace as $field=>$abbrs)
    foreach($abbrs as $abbr)
        $address = str_replace($abbr.' ',$field.' ',$address);
//fields
$fields = array_keys($replace);
//match
if(preg_match_all('/('.implode('|',array_keys($fields)).')\s+([^\s]+)/si', $address, $matches)) {
    //matches
    $search = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
    //other
    $search['other'] = str_replace($matches[0],"",$address);
}else{
    //search in all the fields
    $search['other'] = $address;    
}
//search
print_r($search);
```

Code tester: http://ideone.com/j3q4YI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the help! I thought that I should do something like multiple preg_matches.

I just found a PHP extension that does exactly what I want.

The library is PHP Postal (https://github.com/openvenues/php-postal) and requires libpostal. It takes about 15-20 seconds to load the library when you run PHP, after this everything work ok.

Total execution time for parsing: 0.00030-0.00060 seconds.

```
$parsed = Postal\Parser::parse_address("The Book Club 100-106 Leonard St, Shoreditch, London, Greater London, EC2A 4RH, United Kingdom");
foreach ($parsed as $component) {
    echo "{$component['label']}: {$component['value']}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
house: the book club
house_number: 100-106
road: leonard st
suburb: shoreditch
city: london
state_district: greater london
postcode: ec2a 4rh
country: united kingdom
```

All I had to do after this is to replace my labels and format the address.

Hope this will help others, who want to parse a address in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, you've got one hairy mess to clean up.  I've toiled for a few hours on this.  It works on all of your samples, but I would NOT stake my career on it being perfect on all future cases.  There are simply too many variations in addresses. I hope you can understand my process and modify it if/when new samples failed to be captured properly.  I'll leave all my debugging comment in place, because I reckon you'll use them for future edits.

```
$addresses=array(
    "street Main Road Bulding H7 Number 5 Area 1",
    "st Main Road bldg H7 Nr 5 Ar 5",
    "stMain bldgh7",
    "ar5 unknown other search parameter",
    "street Main Road h7 2b",
    "street main street str main road"
);

$regex["area"]="/^(.*?)(ar(?:ea)?\s?)([1-5])(.*?)$/i";
$regex["number"]="/^(.*?)(n(?:umbe)?r\s?)([0-9]+)(.*?)$/i";
$regex["building"]="/^(.*?)(bu?i?ldi?n?g\s?)([^\s]+)(.*?)$/i";
$regex["corner"]="/^(.*?str?(?:eet)?)\s?(str?(?:eet)?.*)$/i"; // 2 streets in string
$regex["street"]="/^(.*?)(str?(?:eet)?\s?)([^\s]*(?:\s?ro?a?d|\s?str?e?e?t?|.*?))(\s?.*?)$/i";
$regex["other"]="/^(.+)$/";

$search=[];
foreach($addresses as $i=>$address){
    echo "<br><div><b>$address</b> breakdown:</div>";
    foreach($regex as $key=>$rgx){
        if(strlen($address)>0){
            //echo "<div>addr(",strlen($address),") $address</div>";
            if(preg_match($rgx,$address,$matches)){
                if($key=="other"){
                    $search[$i][$key]=$matches[0];  // everything that remains
                }elseif($key=="corner"){
                    $search[$i]["street"]="";  // NOTICE suppression
                    // loop through both halves of corner address omitting element[0]
                    foreach(array_diff_key($matches,array('')) as $half){
                        //echo "half= $half<br>";
                        if(preg_match($regex["street"],$half,$half_matches)){
                            //print_r($half_matches);
                            $search[$i]["street"].=(strlen($search[$i]["street"])>0?"&&":"").ucwords($half_matches[3]);
                            $address=trim($half_matches[1].$half_matches[4]);
                            // $matches[2] is the discarded identifier
                            //echo "<div>$key Found: {$search[$i][$key]}</div>";
                            //echo "<div>Remaining: $address</div>";
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    $search[$i][$key]=($key=="street"?ucwords($matches[3]):$matches[3]);
                    $address=trim($matches[1].$matches[4]);
                    // $matches[2] is the discarded identifier
                    //echo "<div>$key Found: {$search[$i][$key]}</div>";
                    //echo "<div>Remaining: $address</div>";
                    //print_r($matches);
                }
            }
        }else{
            break;  // address is fully processed
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
        var_export($search[$i]);
    echo "</pre>";  
}
```

The output is an array that satisfies your brief, but the keys are out of order because I captured the address components out of order -- this may not matter to you, so I didn't bother re-sorting it.

```
street Main Road Bulding H7 Number 5 Area 1 breakdown:
array (
  'area' => '1',
  'number' => '5',
  'building' => 'H7',
  'street' => 'Main Road',
)

st Main Road bldg H7 Nr 5 Ar 5 breakdown:
array (
  'area' => '5',
  'number' => '5',
  'building' => 'H7',
  'street' => 'Main Road',
)

stMain bldgh7 breakdown:
array (
  'building' => 'h7',
  'street' => 'Main',
)

ar5 unknown other search parameter breakdown:
array (
  'area' => '5',
  'other' => 'unknown other search parameter',
)

street Main Road h7 2b breakdown:
array (
  'street' => 'Main Road',
  'other' => 'h7 2b',
)

street main street str main road breakdown:
array (
  'street' => 'Main Street&&Main Road',
)
```

...boy am I glad this project doesn't belong to me.  Good luck!

Comment: Voting this down since it is unclean, unstable and not at least unmaintainable. That's because it follows the wrong approach. Right would be to force users to input the data in way that the application can handle.

Comment: @hek2mgl I agree it will be unstable because the input can vary so greatly.  This is no fault of mine.  In what way is it not clean?  If you don't like inline condition statements, then that is a matter of personal preference.  It is mostly DRY and doesn't loop unnecessarily.  I find it rude to downvote me after I spent hours trying to help someone, and put forth the only working solution to date.  Downvote the question if you like, but putting me down for trying to help just seems trollish.  Rather than downvoting me, submit your own and let the OP decide.

Comment: What you are trying to do is to write a parser for a language which is used to define address data. But you, or the OP, did not define the rules which describe the language. It can be *anything*. That can't work, it is just wrong. Right would be to point the OP to that fundamental problem instead of giving him the feeling that it can be done *somehow*.

Comment: Btw, having that there would exist strong rules how the address data could look like, a cleaner approach could be to generate a parser using a parser generator. Look at this for example: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190557/how-to-choose-a-proper-parser-generator-for-php